# Linux - start/kill a bash script using keyboard combinations

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, ffmpeg, i3-window-manager

I want to record my screen with a simple ffmpeg command. The problem is I want to do it without opening terminal, for example pressing Ctrl+R to start the script, and again Ctrl+R to kill it. Is that possible?
I use i3 window manager, I can do the starting part, but I have no idea how I could kill it.

Comment: I can just use killall script_name.sh and bind the command to a different key combination. So one combination starts the script, the other one kills it. I just didn't know it was so easy to kill process by script name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the i3 window manager, but it must have keyboard shortcuts. Just set the start & kill shortcuts to whatever key combination you prefer.

I'm familiar with XFCE / XFWM that has a Keyboard settings GUI, with an "Application Shortcuts" tab where you can set any terminal command to just about any key combination.

From a web search for [linux i3 keyboard shortcuts](https://www.google.ca/search?q=linux+i3+keyboard+shortcuts), this hit ( http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-customise-your-linux-desktop-kali-linux-and-i3-window-manager/ ) has a tip that should work. This example runs `gvim` when the "Mod+F4" buttons are pressed:

```
bindsym $mod+F4 exec gvim
```

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know how to kill a process. I'm familiar with binding normal programs. I didn't know killall script.sh would suffice. Thanks for reply though.

Comment: So... the whole *"using  keyboard combinations"* in the title, and *"The problem is I want to do it without opening terminal"* was all just a red herring? That's unusual...